# Where can I find my under-development QGIS plugin folder that I accidentally uninstalled?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a QGIS plugin. I added my plugin via ZIP file and modified it in the folder under the directory `C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\***`. I accidentally uninstalled the plugin and now I'm not able to find the folder anymore. All my changes made are gone. I'm wondering if there is any way to recover my developing plugin that I've just uninstalled?

Comment: I may be wrong but unless your C Drive is backed up and saves a copy regularly so you can recover it then I don't think you can. What GUI did you use to edit it (was it edited within QGIS itself or in another piece of software)?

Comment: You don't make it clear how you deleted it or what operating system you are in but It looks like a Windows directory name. Therefore it is probably worth opening up the recycle folder and having a rummage around.

Comment: @AWGIS I used pycharm to edit it. I tried to find the deleted files in the history but failed.

Comment: @Leigh Bettenay I'm in Windows. I uninstalled the plugin by clicking the "Uninstall plugin" button in the plugins manager before making a copy of the plugin folder. I tried to find it in the recycle folder but it was not there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a file recovery / data recovery software. Windows does not *delete* files by default, even if you empty the recycle bin. It just marks the space on your harddrive as free. If this "free" space is not overwritten you have a good chance to get your data and files back. Keep in mind that Windows is writing (temporary) files all the time on C:/. So avoid to write new data on that harddrive and hurry up with that process.

There are plenty of free and payed software tools out there. I dont want to advertise here for a specific one, but a quick search will give you some results and software reviews.